# Expression-bodied function members in previous C#

Tags: c#

i'm currently wokring with c#6 but need to go back to VS2013 for a project so would like to know if the following Expression-bodied function member has an equal 'sugar' like implimentation in the previous version of C#:

```
public string FullAddress => $"{Title} {FirstName} {LastName}, {Street}, {City} {ZIP}";
```

Title, FirstName, Lastname etc are all other properties that are initialised in the class before FullAddress is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really, the easiest you can do is:

```
public string FullAddress
{
   get 
   {
       return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", 
           Title, FirstName, LastName, Street, City, ZIP);
   }
}
```

You will unfortunately miss both the expression body and string interpolation syntax.

Comment: You have one parameter too much.

Comment: True that :-D fixed

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no shorthand other than:

```
public string FullAddress
{ get { return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}, {3}, {4} {5}", Title, FirstName, LastName, Street, City, ZIP); } }
```

Comment: No, it does not. I just focussed on the expression, but you are right. It doesn't.

Comment: @Saruman String interpolation should work in c# 6 and VS 2013.

Comment: OP uses the version before 6. @GryphG

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I confused the c# version from vs2013.